# How can colored terminal output be disabled for sbt/play?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I would like to disable the color escape codes logged from sbt/play. Is this possible? And if it is, is there a way to do it without making changes to the config - i.e. via a command line switch or system property.

Comment: Consider accepting Steven Shaws answer now?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can simply set the system property `sbt.log.noformat` to `true`. If you want to e.g. use SBT inside Vim you can create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar "${HOME}/bin/sbt-launch.jar" "$@"
```

Comment: This also works as an argument to sbt itself: `sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true`, and if you use [sbt "the rebel cut"](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras), you can use the argument `-no-colors`.

Comment: @jilen - Do you have an example of it for play? I can't seem to figure out how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22665543/20770

Answer (score 64):

Since version `0.13.8` (and possibly earlier) you can now simply use the `-no-colors` option to sbt. e.g.

```
sbt -no-colors test
```

Comment: this is a better answer than the accepted answer if you are using a more recent version of sbt

Comment: what's the point of having the two commands though? `dependencies` is not even a valid sbt command in my sbt setup.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `test` instead of `dependencies`, and made the implicit point about sbt version explicit. This should address @matanster points.

Comment: I get an error "Not a valid command: no-colors" running on sbt 0.13.13

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your platform does not match the actual jline.terminal property. I am just guessing here but when I pass the parameter as Daniel suggested on a Windows command line I see the color escape codes as well.

Therefore, you have to make sure the property matches your platform, i.e. WindowsTerminal on Windows and UnixTerminal on Unix.

If this does not help, then you might be on an unsupported platform in which case the [website](http://jline.sourceforge.net/index.html) suggests to use:

```
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
```

Comment: Sorry to clarify, it is not that the colouring does not work, just that I want to be able to disable. @Moritz's answer helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can *get* colors on Windows by installing Cygwin and passing this parameter:

```
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal
```

So I'd look up jline parameters to see what disables color coding.

Comment: Ar you using rxvt or mintty? Under default cygwin console using cmd.exe I'm getting that kind of output: `←[0m[←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0mBuilding project`...

Comment: @huynhjl No, I never tried to get that tip to work. I'm a bit suprised at the output, though. What's the value of TERM?

Comment: TERM is set to cygwin. The main annoyance I have with cygwin right now is that multi line editing does not work (once it wraps, can't go back and edit previous line with the right visual feedback). I've figured out that jline can't deal with ansi code on win32 under cygwin. So I was interested to see how color would have worked with sbt..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get colored output from SBT in Cygwin by adding:

```
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal
```

Additionally I figured out that I also needed to add the following line to Cygwin.bat:

```
set CYGWIN=tty ntsec
```

After that is added SBT gives very nice colored output. Additionally I would recommend looking into Console2 as it can hook through Cygwin, but provides a much better interface in my opinion:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: i've tried with both console2 and cmd and there're a few problems: tab completion does not work, backspace does not work, exception Invalid terminal type: jline.UnixTerminal when starting console