# Play - disable Logger colors

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

I'm using `play.api.Logger` to log in my Play application like:

```
import play.api.Logger
Logger.info("message to log")
```

By default this will use shell colors resulting in something like this

> [[37minfo[0m] application - message to log

if the terminal you're using doesn't support colors.

Is there a way to tell `Logger` to not use colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267014/how-can-colored-terminal-output-be-disabled-for-sbt-play). The `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true` disables console log colors.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the log pattern inside conf/logback.xml. The default pattern is:

```
<pattern>%coloredLevel - %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
```

You could change it to:

```
<pattern>%level - %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure sbt/activator to show logs entries without colors.
Just start it with property `-no-colors`