# When building chisel using sbt how do I turn off the progress bars etc. so that the output is clean?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

When building chisel using sbt, when run as a batch process, how do I turn off the progress bars etc. so that the output is clean like I get with most compilers?

That is, I like to build chisel using sbt from within a makefile, like this:

```
${VLOG_DIR}/${NAME}.v: ${NAME}.scala
        setsid sbt \
          'runMain ${NAME}.${NAME} --top-name ${NAME} --target-dir ${VLOG_DIR}'
```

However sbt/scala/chisel like to attempt to generate some sort of progress bars while building that emit terminal escape codes to attempt to update the output in place.  When run inside my shell this does not work very well, but when run inside emacs it makes a huge mess:

```
make
setsid sbt \
  'runMain HelloWorld.HelloWorld --top-name HelloWorld --target-dir Gen_HelloWor\
ld.verilog_dir'
^[[0m[^[[0m^[[0minfo^[[0m] ^[[0m^[[0mLoading project definition from /home/user/h\
ello-chisel/project^[[0m
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[5A^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K  | => hello-chisel-build / update 0s
^[[6A^[[2K
^[[2K
```

Especially when there is an error message:

```
^[[2K
^[[2K
^[[2K  | => hello-chisel / Compile / compileIncremental 1s
^[[6A^[[2K^[[0m[^[[0m^[[31merror^[[0m] ^[[0m^[[0m/home/user/hello-chisel/HelloWor\
ld.scala:46:17: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:^[[0m
^[[2K
```

How do I turn all of that off and get normal looking output having clean error messages?

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

Pass `-no-colors` to `sbt` on the command line, per the
[sbt FAQ](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Faq.html#How+do+I+disable+ansi+codes+in+the+output%3F):

```
$ sbt -no-colors 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain'
```

Despite the name "no colors", it suppresses all terminal escape stuff, including the progress bars.

### Other alternatives

The option can also be spelled `--no-colors` (two hyphens), which is how it appears in the output of `sbt --help` (and `sbt -help`).

The same effect can be achieved by passing `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true` to `sbt` (or to `java` if invoking that directly) as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269307/2659307):

```
$ sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain'
```

It can also be achieved by setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable to `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true`:

```
$ JAVA_OPTS=-Dsbt.log.noformat=true sbt 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain'
```

If you are using [`sbt-launch.jar`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Getting-Started.html), then you have to use the `-D` switch because `-no-colors` is not recognized in that context (the `sbt` shell script is what recognizes `-no-colors`):

```
$ java -jar ~/opt/sbt-1.3.4/bin/sbt-launch.jar -Dsbt.log.noformat=true 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain'
```

Finally, when `sbt` detects that its stdout is not a TTY, it will suppress color output:

```
$ sbt 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain' | cat
```

That's not a good option in a Makefile though because you lose the exit status of `sbt` (without further [shenanigans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)).

Unfortunately, `sbt` does *not* respect [`NO_COLOR`](https://no-color.org/).

### Chisel output has some colors anyway

When using [Chisel](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3), for example the [chisel template](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template), even with `-no-colors`, some terminal escape codes appear in the output anyway:

```
$ sbt -no-colors 'test:runMain gcd.GCDMain' | cat -tev
[info] Loading settings for project chisel-template-build from plugins.sbt ...$
[info] Loading project definition from /home/scott/wrk/learn/chisel/chisel-template/project$
[info] Loading settings for project chisel-template from build.sbt ...$
[info] Set current project to chisel-module-template (in build file:/home/scott/wrk/learn/chisel/chisel-template/)$
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list$
[info] running gcd.GCDMain $
[^[[35minfo^[[0m] [0.001] Elaborating design...$
[^[[35minfo^[[0m] [1.064] Done elaborating.$
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 512.0 ms$
file loaded in 0.114380184 seconds, 22 symbols, 17 statements$
[^[[35minfo^[[0m] [0.001] SEED 1581769687441$
test GCD Success: 168 tests passed in 1107 cycles in 0.047873 seconds 23123.91 Hz$
[^[[35minfo^[[0m] [0.037] RAN 1102 CYCLES PASSED$
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Feb 15, 2020 4:28:09 AM$
```

Note the `[^[[35minfo^[[0m]` output near the end.  This happens because [chiselFrontend/src/main/scala/chisel3/internal/Error.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/v3.2.2/chiselFrontend/src/main/scala/chisel3/internal/Error.scala) unconditionally prints color escape sequences (see the `tag` function), which is arguably a bug in Chisel since its output is clearly meant to look similar to `sbt` output.

### Effect of setsid

In your example Makefile, you're invoking `sbt` via [`setsid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html).  As far as I can tell, everything I've said applies equally to that circumstance.  However, you probably want to pass `--wait` to `setsid` so it will wait for `sbt` to complete before exiting.  In my testing, `setsid` will implicitly wait only when stdout is not a TTY, but I doubt you actually want that hidden variability.