# Why is Play framework logging so verbose?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am implementing a simple REST service using the Play Framework and sbt as my build tool. When I execute `sbt run` and start my server, I see some strange logging that I do not understand: `<-[2k`. I was hoping somebody could tell me what is causing it or how to turn it off.

[image: Logging from sbt run]

Comment: you need to disable color output in sbt. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267014/how-can-colored-terminal-output-be-disabled-for-sbt-play). `sbt -no-colors run` should do the trick

Comment: I ran `sbt -no-colors run` and all that 2k stuff disappeared. Thank you.